# Как реализовать ввод в EditText через Button, а не клавиатуру?

Tags: java, android

Допустим в активити будет одна кнопка и неопределенное количество edittext. Когда мы нажимаем на edittext, клавиатура не появляется, но если мы нажмем на кнопку, то в edittext введется то, что мы определим в программе Java.
Как такое сделать?

Comment: Это же первый класс. На кнопку вешаетe слушатель клика, где прописываете присвоение edittext любого текста через settext. А у edittext ставите enabled false

Comment: @ArtyMorris  дело в том, что я не знаю как определить текущий выбранный edittext через код. У меня их несколько, даже очень много, а значит надо определять какой я выбрал. Это единственная проблема, и как ее решить?

Comment: в этом случае вам не нужен EditText, используйте TextView

Comment: @Style-7 А есть, собственно, какая-то разница? Что то подойдёт, что это

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать глобальную переменную которая будет соответствовать текущему выбранному полю для ввода:

```
private EditText currentView;
```

у данного типа виджетов есть слушатель фокуса:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

вы можете сделать его общим для всех ваших виджетов поля ввода:

```
 private View.OnFocusChangeListener listener = (view, hasFocus) -> {
        if (hasFocus) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    };
```

дальше в слушателе когда у вас есть фокус вы присваиваете `currentView` значение `view`:
if (hasFocus) {
currentView = (EditText) view;
} else {
...
}

и добавляете слушатель к каждому `EditText` которых у вас большое кол-во:

```
myEtxt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
```

ну и наконец у кнопки вы можете добавить ее включение/отключение:

```
myBtn.setEnabled(currentView != null);
```

и в слушателе нажатий устанавливаете текст в поле для ввода которое вы выбрали.

Comment: Ого, спасибо вам большое за ответ